# Add new itemeventreceiver methods in visual studio on top of existing event receiver

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, item-added, item-deleted

I have developed an item event receiver with itemadded and itemupdated event handler using VS 2013 against SP 2013 ON-PREM soln.

Now as per my updated requirements, I need to add a new itemdeleted/itemdeleting  and ItemAttachmentAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) etc kind of event receivers on top of this.

How can I do this using the VS designer surface? is there any shortcut key for this to open up for adding more item event receiver methods on top of existing item event receivers?

I want to get this UI Dialog back again for adding few more methods:

[image: add-this-UI-AGAIN]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this dialog is only opened during creating a new event receiver

Meanwhile, you can achieve your goal ( `I need to add a new itemdeleted/itemdeleting and ItemAttachmentAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) etc`) easily by doing the following:

- Right click on your event receiver as shown below > select `Properties`.

[image]

- All events should be listed as shown below.

[image]

- Just check which event you will need then change it from **false** to **true**.
- The event function should be now added as shown below.

[image]

Comment: thats nice to know! :-) i will try to implement and revert here!

Comment: Take your time :) hope it help you :)

Comment: Hi @SaMolPP Do you get another answer for your question? Please If this answer solved your question, mark it as the accepted to be useful for future visitors. Thank You!